# Algorithm to distribute evenly products value into care packages

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, data-structures

i'm currently solving a problem that states:

A company filed for bankruptcy and decided to pay the employees with the last remaining valuable items in the company only if it can be distributed evenly among them so that all of them have at least received 1 item and that the difference between the employee carrying the most valuable items and the employee carrying the least valuable items can not exceed a certain value x;
Input:

- First row contains number of employee;
- Second row contains the x value so that the the difference between the employee carrying the most valuable items and the employee carrying the least valuable items can not exceed;
- Third row contains all the items with their value;
  Output:
- First number is the least valuable basket of items value and the second is the most valuable basket;

Example:

Input:

5

4

2 5 3 11 4 3 1 15 7 8 10

Output:
13 15

Input:

5

4

1 1 1 11 1 3 1 2 7 8

Output:
NO (It's impossible to distribute evenly)

Input:

5

10

1 1 1 1

Output:
NO (It's impossible to distribute evenly)

My solution to resolve this problem taking the first input is to, sort the items in ascending or descending order so from

 2 5 3 11 4 3 1 15 7 8 10 --> 1 2 3 3 4 5 7 8 10 11 15

 then create an adjacency list or just store it in simple variables where we add the biggest number to the lowest basket while iterating the item values array

 Element 0: 15

 Element 1: 11 <- 3 (sum 14)

 Element 2: 10 <- 3 (sum 13)

 Element 3: 8 <- 4 <- 1 (sum 13)

 Element 4: 7 <- 5 <- 2 (sum 14)

 So that my solution will have O(nlogN + 2n), first part using merge sort and then finding max e min value, what do you guys think about this solution?

Comment: The case of two employees and x=0 is already NP-complete: [The partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). The algorithm you propose is known as [greedy number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_number_partitioning) which gets you within 17% of optimal.

Comment: So in this case it doesn't exist a provable optimal solution that doesn't use a brute force approach?

Comment: @ValerioJiang: Yes, that's basically what it means if an algorithm is NP-complete.